# I can't install certain Python libraries because of "ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils'"

Tags: python, python3, pip, matplotlib, tensorflow

I'm trying to upgrade from Python 3.5 to 3.8.3, and TensorFlow 1.13 to 2.2, so I can be up to date. However, having two versions of Python3 on my computer has caused a whole headache of problems. (I have the python3 command linked to Python3.8 now, though!)

By the way, I make YouTube videos about programming on the channel carykh (someone told me to say that so my question wouldn't get ignored).

Earlier today, I was able to install `tensorflow-gpu`, but later today, after uninstalling it, I wasn't able to install it again because of the error in the title and the code below. When I try to install matplotlib, it fails with the same error. It's annoying, because these installations worked without a hitch for Python 3.5 for me. Can anyone help me figure out what's going on? Thanks so much in advance!

```
rob@robusic-land:/$ python3 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/__init__.py)
```

I saw similar questions saying to try the installations below, but they resulted in errors themselves, or didn't result in any change of behavior...

```
rob@robusic-land:/$ sudo apt-get install python-distutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-distutils
rob@robusic-land:/$ sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-distutils
rob@robusic-land:/$ sudo apt-get install python-distutils-extra
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-distutils-extra is already the newest version (2.39-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to run software intended for 20.04 or 20.10 (Py 3.8.2+) on a 16.04 (Py 3.5.1) system. It's likely you broke your system when you changed the Python3 symlink to 3.8. I would change it back. In general, it's much easier and more reliable to run a newer release of Ubuntu in order to get newer software, even if it's simply in a VM.